# Dataframe group by and multi aggregate

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe from a pd.read_sql_query structured like:

```
tabla       nombre_razon                          periodos
Bancos  |   ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA       |   [201801,201902]
Bancos  |   CIELO PLAST EIRL                |   [201702]
Bancos  |   COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO   |   [201801,201902,202001]
Bancos  |   COPLASTICA SAC                  |   [202203, 202102, 202110, 202105, 202206]
Bancos  |   ECOPET PERU SAC                 |   [201801,201902]
Ventas  |   ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA       |   [202201, 202202, 202109, 202107]
Ventas  |   GRUPO ELIAPAC SAC               |   [202207, 202209, 202205, 202203, 202109]
Ventas  |   COPLASTICA SAC                  |   [201801,201902]
Ventas  |   ECOPET PERU SAC                 |   [201801,201902]
Ventas  |   KENTHIVAS SAC                   |   [202208, 202201, 202112, 202202]
Compras |   ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA       |   [201801,201902]
Compras |   CIELO PLAST EIRL                |   [202204, 202201, 202202, 202209]
Compras |   COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO   |   [201801,201902]
Compras |   ECOPET PERU SAC                 |   [202201, 202107, 202108, 202109]
Compras |   KENTHIVAS SAC                   |   [201801,201902]
```

And I would like to transform it to the following List:

```
[['Bancos','Ventas','Compras'],[['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA','CIELO PLAST EIRL','COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO','COPLASTICA SAC','ECOPET PERU SAC'],['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA','GRUPO ELIAPAC SAC','COPLASTICA SAC','ECOPET PERU SAC','KENTHIVAS SAC'],['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA','CIELO PLAST EIRL','COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO','ECOPET PERU SAC','KENTHIVAS SAC']],[[['201801','201902'],['201702'],['201801','201902','202001'],['202203','202102','202110','202105', '202206'],['201801','201902']],[['202201','202202','202109','202107'],['202207','202209','202205','202203','202109'],['201801','201902'],['201801','201902'],['202208','202201','202112','202202']],[['201801','201902'],['202204','202201', '202202','202209'],['201801','201902'],['202201','202107','202108','202109'],['201801','201902']]]]
```

I've tried ways like this:

```
dataFrame.groupby(['tabla', 'nombre_razon','periodos'])
```

or

```
comboGeneral2['periodo_tributario']=comboGeneral2['periodo_tributario'].apply(str)
    
comboGeneral1=comboGeneral3.groupby('tabla')['nombre_razon','periodo_tributario'].agg(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index()
```

without success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate lists with tranpose, converting to numpy array and then to lists:

```
import ast

#if necessary
#dataFrame['periodos'] = dataFrame['periodos'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

L = (dataFrame.groupby('tabla', sort=False)[['nombre_razon','periodos']]
              .agg(list)
              .reset_index()
              .T
              .to_numpy()
              .tolist())
print (L)

[['Bancos', 'Ventas', 'Compras'],
 [['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA', 'CIELO PLAST EIRL', 
   'COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO', 'COPLASTICA SAC', 'ECOPET PERU SAC'],
  ['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA', 'GRUPO ELIAPAC SAC', 'COPLASTICA SAC',
   'ECOPET PERU SAC', 'KENTHIVAS SAC'], 
  ['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA', 'CIELO PLAST EIRL',
   'COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO', 'ECOPET PERU SAC', 'KENTHIVAS SAC']],
 [[[201801, 201902], [201702], [201801, 201902, 202001], 
   [202203, 202102, 202110, 202105, 202206], [201801, 201902]],
  [[202201, 202202, 202109, 202107], [202207, 202209, 202205, 202203, 202109],
   [201801, 201902], [201801, 201902], [202208, 202201, 202112, 202202]],
  [[201801, 201902], [202204, 202201, 202202, 202209], [201801, 201902],
   [202201, 202107, 202108, 202109], [201801, 201902]]]]
```

If need strings `periods`:

```
dataFrame['periodos'] = [[str(y) for y in x] for x in dataFrame['periodos']]

L = (dataFrame.groupby('tabla', sort=False)[['nombre_razon','periodos']]
              .agg(list)
              .reset_index()
              .T
              .to_numpy()
              .tolist())
```

For verify your expected ouput:

```
# [['Bancos','Ventas','Compras'],
#  [['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA','CIELO PLAST EIRL',
#    'COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO','COPLASTICA SAC','ECOPET PERU SAC'],
#   ['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA','GRUPO ELIAPAC SAC',
#    'COPLASTICA SAC','ECOPET PERU SAC','KENTHIVAS SAC'],
#   ['ALIAGA ORTIZ LILIA ROXANA','CIELO PLAST EIRL',
#    'COCHACHIN AGUIRRE ELIAS PABLO','ECOPET PERU SAC','KENTHIVAS SAC']],
#  [[['201801','201902'],['201702'],['201801','201902','202001'],
#    ['202203','202102','202110','202105', '202206'],['201801','201902']],
#   [['202201','202202','202109','202107'],
#    ['202207','202209','202205','202203','202109'],['201801','201902'],
#    ['201801','201902'],['202208','202201','202112','202202']],
#   [['201801','201902'],['202204','202201', '202202','202209'],
#    ['201801','201902'],['202201','202107','202108','202109'],
#    ['201801','201902']]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have noticed that each list is inside another individual list, it may just be a list, for example going from [['202108', '202109']] to ['202108', '202109'] or from [[202201, 202107, 202108, 202109]] to [202201, 202107, 202108, 202109], it's posible?

Comment: @Raknaros - seems it was in my previous answer, not solution is changed - I hope now expected ouput is correct.

Comment: @Raknaros - I just change order of final lists by add `sort=False` to ouput, do you need years like strings? Or my ouput is correct?

Comment: Adding a bit, to convert the periods to string I use L5['periods']=L5['periods'].apply(lambda lst: list(map(str, lst)))

Comment: @Raknaros - Super, it is another good solution.